# Wait to code inside function $.get done to continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have doing a website with javascript but I can't do that I want.

I have this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
res = new Array();

var fun1 = function () {
var control = $.Deferred();
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    $.get("URL", function(data){
        res[i]=data;
        console.log ("i is: " + i + "and res is: " + res);
    });
    }
}

setTimeout(function () {
control.resolve();
}, 3000);

var show = function () {
console.log("Res finally is: " + res);
}

fun1().done(show);  
</script>
```

I want to do a $.get with 5 or more different URL (I have a param in the URL) but I can't do it. res[i] is always the last element in the array (in this case is always res[5]=data and I want to fill the complete array, from 0 to 15.

First console.log always show

```
i is:  5 and res is: ,,,,,20
i is:  5 and res is: ,,,,,10
...
i is:  5 and res is: ,,,,,38
```

and the second console.log always return the last

```
Res finally is ,,,,,38
```

How can I do it correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Comment: This question is really two questions. It's best in general to keep questions distinct, to post them separately. epascarello's duplicate answers one of your two questions; the other relates to combining promises (and there's almost certainly an answer here about that, too, but we can only close a question as a dupe of *one* other question...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with `i` is that your callbacks close over the **variable** `i`, not its value as of when the function was created. So they all see `i = 5`.

I'm not quite understanding why you're repeating the `get` five times, but if you want to, you have to give the callbacks something else to close over (or use `res.push(...)` rather than `res[i] = ...`, but I assume you have a reason for the latter).

You can do that using a builder:

```
// PARTIAL solution, see below
var fun1 = function () {
    var control = $.Deferred();
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        $.get("URL", buildHandler(i));
    }

    function buildHandler(index) {
        return function(data){
            res[index]=data;
            console.log ("index is: " + index + "and res is: " + res);
        };
    }
};
```

Another way to do a builder is to use `Function#bind` (ES5+, but easily polyfilled), but you'd create more functions than you need; the above is more efficient in this case (not that it likely matters).

Then, to have `fun1` return something useful, you have it return a promise (you seem to be on your way to that, based on your `control` variable), and then fulfill the promise when all of the `get`s are done (`$.when` is useful for that):

```
var fun1 = function () {
    var control = $.Deferred();
    var promises = [];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        promises.push($.get("URL", buildHandler(i)));
    }
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        control.resolve(); // Or .resolveWith(), passing in something useful
    });

    return control.promise();

    function buildHandler(index) {
        return function(data){
            res[index]=data;
            console.log ("index is: " + index + "and res is: " + res);
        };
    }
};
```

All of this assumes `res` is in scope for this code; you haven't shown where it comes from.